# Adding 2 integers in 1 User input

Tags: java

I want to make the user input 2 integers in 1 input like this

> Enter two integers: 2 2 // sum = 4

Here is my sample code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x, num1, num2, sum;
        
    System.out.print("*Enter 2 integer: ");
    x = s.nextInt();

    
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    System.out.println(" Sum = "+ sum);
```

Is it possible to add 2 integers without using variables num1 and num2?
I want the output to be like this.

> Enter two integers: 2 2

> sum = 4

Comment: Q: Is it possible to add 2 integers without using variables?  A: Sure.  You can use three variables (int i = j + k), two variables and a literal (int i = j+2), the same variable twice (int i=j+j), etc. etc.  You can also read directly from s.nextInt(), without saving to any extra variables at all.  Q: What do you *WANT* to use for your addends?

Comment: Another solution is to take input as a string. Then use whitespace as a separator to get all different numbers and then conver those numbers from string to int and then add them.

Answer (score 0):

Add any number of integers:

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter some integers: ");
int sum = 0;
while (s.hasNextInt()) {
    sum += s.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(" Sum = " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Case 1:

- If you have only 2 values then follow the below code

  import java.util.*;

  class Add {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  ```
       int sum = 0;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("*Enter 2 integer: ");

       for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
           sum += scan.nextInt();

       System.out.println(" Sum = "+ sum);
   }
  ```

  }

### Case 2:

- If you have some More than 2 numbers but you have an idea about how many numbers to sum then follow the below code.

  import java.util.*;

  class Add {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  ```
       int sum = 0;
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("*Enter how many integers to sum: ");
       int iterate = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.print("*Enter " + iterate + " integer: ");

       while(iterate-- > 0)
           sum += scan.nextInt();

       System.out.println(" Sum = "+ sum);
   }
  ```

  }